# Can we prove the epsilon theorems without the axiom of choice?

Tags: lo.logic, axiom-of-choice, metamathematics

Hilbert's epsilon $\epsilon$ is a quantifier. It follows the rule that if $\exists x. p(x)$, for some predicate $p$, we can infer $p(\epsilon x. p(x))$. Semantically, it represents picking some element $x$ that satisfies $p(x)$, or an arbitrary element otherwise. Another common inference rule is that if $p(x) \equiv q(x)$, then $\epsilon x. p(x) = \epsilon y. q(y)$.

Without the axiom of choice, the semantics no longer make sense, but the syntax still does. Can we prove the [epsilon theorems](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/epsilon-calculus/#3) without it?

Comment: Also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/281301/can-adding-hilberts-epsilon-to-a-theory-and-then-expanding-that-theories-axiom

Comment: Also, in the second inference rule you have $p(x)$ and $q(x)$, and then $p(x)$ and $p(y)$. Something is off...

Comment: @AsafKaragila fixed

Comment: I'm a bit confused. The epsilon theorems are about derivability in a fixed formal system; these are purely combinatorial (or broadly number-theoretic) facts, and have nothing to do with the axiom of choice. (Massive overkill: the epsilon theorems are arithmetic statements, and we have absoluteness between $V$ and $L$ for such statements in ZF ...) So is this really what you're asking?

Comment: @NoahSchweber oh, I forgot about absoluteness. Sorry.

Comment: Since you are asking about set-theoretic uses of $\varepsilon$, it  seems natural to interpret $\varepsilon$ in the context of second-order set theory as providing a global choice function. In this case, if one has the comprehension axiom in the language with $\varepsilon$, then it would not be provable in GB+AC, since it would be equivalent to global choice. For example, see http://jdh.hamkins.org/the-global-choice-principle-in-godel-bernays-set-theory/.

Comment: @NoahSchweber actually, wait mind. What about an uncountable set of formulae?

Comment: @PyRulez That corresponds to a real parameter, and doesn't affect anything.

Comment: @NoahSchweber what if it's even greater than the cardinality of the reals?

Comment: @PyRulez Well, you can't have that unless your language is uncountable. But actually, since "$\vdash$" is compact, even that doesn't matter: a statement of the form "$\Gamma\vdash\varphi$" is absolute, regardless of how big $\Gamma$ is.

Comment: It is reasonably clear from the linked SEP article that the original proofs were finitistic (that was kind of the whole point of the enterprise), so they wouldn’t use the axiom of choice in the first place.

Comment: @Joel: Your comment here matches your answer on the question I mention in my first comment.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Arithmetical absoluteness is very massive overkill. I've seen people invoke Shoenfield absoluteness in similar situations.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Oh yes, I never intended to imply it wasn't. (But SA is even worse!)

Comment: @NoahSchweber Oops; I intended to write "not" before "very".  I agree it's overkill, but I wanted to point out that it could get even worse.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Either way, the mosquito is dead.